# Why following Couchbase async Python code does not work?

Tags: python, couchbase

Consider following piece of code:

```
import asyncio
from acouchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import ClusterOptions
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator

async def do_crud_op():
    cb = Cluster.connect("couchbase://localhost", options=ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator("user", "password")))
    cb = cb.bucket('customers')
    await cb.upsert('id', {'some': 'value'})
    return await cb.get('id')
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
rv = loop.run_until_complete(do_crud_op())
print(rv.value)
```

I am using Python 3.0 SDK and COuchbase 6.5.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. The above code gives me `LCB_ERR_NO_CONFIGURATION` exception. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found out that we need to wait on bucket variable using `on_connect` method to make it work.

```
import asyncio
from acouchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import ClusterOptions
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator

async def do_crud_op():
    cb = Cluster.connect("couchbase://localhost", options=ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator("user", "password")))
    cb = cb.bucket('customers')
    await cb.on_connect()
    await cb.upsert('id', {'some': 'value'})
    return await cb.get('id')
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
rv = loop.run_until_complete(do_crud_op())
print(rv.value)
```